# Story where inert, indestructible alien devices appear all across Earth

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

One day, billions of hovering, featureless alien objects appear out of thin air in a grid pattern across the Earth's surface. Initially, they cause car and plane crashes, but they do nothing for decades. The protagonist's family tries to leave their house when the incident occurs, but run into one while pulling out of the driveway. Nuclear bombs have no effect. Families name their objects and decorate them for the holidays. At the end of the story, the protagonist realizes they have been attacking humanity in a subtle way, though I don't remember how. This was a short story published before 2017.

Comment: This is quite similar to a Doctor Who episode "The Power of Three" from 2012 https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Power_of_Three_(Doctor_Who)

Comment: Reminiscent of "Slow Birds" but not close enough for an answer.

Comment: Its not Dr. Who or Slow Birds, I'm fairly sure the objects were completely stationary.

Comment: @qazwsx Did you read it online? In an anthology? A magazine? You say before 2017. Is that because you remember reading it in 2017?

Comment: I know I have read this one, but it must have been a very long time ago. I'm pretty sure it was in a book -- and that's as far as my memory goes; I have no idea what other stories were in the book, nor what the overall theme was (if the book even had one?).

Comment: I have definitely read this, in one of those "Year's Best SF" type anthologies, but also can't remember when :(